# Roof ticking noise during daytime

Tags: walls, noise

I’ve moved into a new place that was built end of last year and have been hearing ticking noises (upstairs only) throughout the day at random times. Heating or cooling is switched off. I’ve uploaded two short clips to hopefully illustrate the issue. The issue seem to happen the most during the day, but - not as loud - has also recently started happening early in the morning (1am - 3am) which has woken me up a couple of times.

Does anyone know where this might be coming from and how to fix it?

[1] https://youtu.be/k1C-IIxmIug

[2] https://youtu.be/q0maBMKaUk4

Comment: Probably the roof itself expanding / contracting... Usually the roof is constructed to have sliding joints to prevent this nuisance.

Comment: Do you have a truss roof? Our house was built in 1971 and we bought it in '78. There was a lot of roof ticking at first, attributed to expansion and contraction in the truss roof. Somewhere along the line between then and now the ticking stopped.

Answer (score 1):

At 2am, this is almost certainly the roof itself (or the gutters) cooling down overnight and contracting.  Ticking during the day would be the roof expanding in the heat.

A 13C temperature range is quite enough to do this.

There probably isn't a fix.  If it is a gutter you might be able to lubricate where it passes through the brackets.

Comment: You could add, based on my comment, about sliding joints or sound deadening material...

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that at the moment it is winter. Temperature outside would probably be 0 to -2C.

Comment: @Tickticktick - much more relevant, what is the daytime high vs nighttime low?  It doesn't really matter if the temperature is varying from +20C to +35C or from -20C to -5C.  (For the pedants around here: there would probably be more ticking at the lower range.)

Comment: @SolarMike I didn't understand your comment.  Sliding joints is exactly where I would expect the ticking to come from - as the two parts slide past each other.

Comment: @MartinBonner today's temp is min 0 and max 13. During the warmer days from video [2] above, the max temperature probably reached 32C. The noise was much louder compared to what it is now. Is there some sort of fix for this? :\

Comment: Just saw the following post. The sound is very familiar! https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/158788/how-do-i-stop-the-ticking-noise-coming-from-my-furnace-duct?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Tickticktick If you think your question is a duplicate of that, I *think* you can close it as such.

Comment: You may also have considerably greater temperature range of the roof itself - depending on sun exposure. I have a dark blue roof that will hit 25°C or more on a -10°C day due to solar heating.